# Unable to access React dev server: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, server

I am trying to run a React application locally using `npm start`, but I am unable to connect to it through the browser (tried both Chrome and Firefox). I receive the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

The server appears to start correctly according to the console output:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view frontend in the browser.

Local: http://localhost:3000
On Your Network: http://192.168.0.12:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

I also have a Django API server running on port 8000, which I'm routing to using http-proxy-middleware in a setupProxy.js file:

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware";

export default function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/api",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:8000",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
}
```

Here are the troubleshooting steps I've already taken:

- Checked the URL for typos.
- Confirmed that the React dev server is indeed running on port 3000, and the Django server is running on port 8000.
- Checked my system's firewall settings to make sure it's not blocking the connection.
- Restarted the development server and my entire computer.
- Tested the connection in different browsers.
- Confirmed that there are no error messages in the browser console.
- Checked for other processes using port 3000 using the lsof -i :3000 command (there were none).
- Checked my /etc/hosts file to confirm that localhost is correctly configured.
- Pinging localhost in the terminal works correctly.
- Tried running the React server on a different port (3001), but the issue persisted.
- Tried accessing the server using the IP address (http://192.168.0.12:3000), but the issue persisted.
  Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: where do you run the proxy and why do you need it ?

Comment: The proxy is just to make the API call URLs cleaner and to be able to easily change the address when I deploy. I tried removing the proxy setup and still getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to connect to the node server.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Removed all proxy settings and ran `npm restart`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).